# Direct code execution through the JS browser console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the code below, and it works perfectly up to the 12th item ...

In this case I created this script to like a post on Facebook in pure JS, but as I said, when it arrives at item 12 it stops clicking on the element "document.querySelector ('. Q9uorilb.sf5mxxl7.bdca9zbp'). Click ()" that is the query that gives like

Does anyone know what can it be? Is it some limiting feature of Facebook likes maybe?

codic

```js
var likes = 0;
var time = 10000
document.querySelectorAll('.l9j0dhe7.soycq5t1').forEach((item, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    item.click()
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('.q9uorilb.sf5mxxl7.bdca9zbp').click()
    }, 9000)
    likes++; //+1 "likes"
    console.log(`You liked a total of $ {likes} posts!`);
    if (likes == 10) return time = 30000
    else if (likes == 20) return time = 50000
    else if (likes >= 30) return time = 80000
  }, index * time)
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the event is getting fired? can you put a `console.log()` inside the `setTimeout()` to make sure it's getting fired?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you think `return time = 80000` is doing. Do you think it is altering the setTimeout length?

Comment: YYes! I think that in the condition of if, if the likes are equal to the value I determined it changes the time value. @epascarello

Comment: I did the test that told me and yes, the console.log always returns the message to me @sagar1025

Comment: @MatheusNascimento by the time that return runs, all your timeouts have already been run. So it is doing nothing.